# Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Missing template name in SMARTY

Tags: smarty

I want change content of a block with a condition (isset($file)) but i saw an error Missing template name when i run my code

```
public function food_list()
{
    $m_food=new M_food();
    $arr=$m_food->food_list();
    $smarty=new Smarty_restaurant();
    $smarty->assign("title","New food");
    //$smarty->assign("file","../../views/v_food_list.tpl");
    //$smarty->assign("arr",$arr);
    $smarty->display ("food_list.tpl");
}
```

And this is food_list.tpl file

```
{extends file="index.tpl"}
{block name="head"}{include file="head-food.tpl"}{/block}
{block name="slide"}{/block}
{if isset($file)}
{block name="content"}{include file=$file}{/block}
{else}
{block name="content"}{/block}
{/if}
```

I got an error Missing template name when i add // before $smarty->assign("file","../../views/v_food_list.tpl")
I need a detail answer for my problem,please help me.Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `{block}` are compiled before the rest of Smarty file, so you should try to change your Smarty file into:

```
{extends file="index.tpl"}
{block name="head"}{include file="head-food.tpl"}{/block}
{block name="slide"}{/block}
{block name="content"}
{if isset($file)}
{include file=$file}
{/if}
{/block}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the variable $file is unset or empty.
You should make sure your variable $file is not empty and its value is valid template path.